# Laravel can't create custom UserProvider Class not found

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to create a custom auth provider in laravel.
I already added a new provider in the `config/auth.php` and also created a Class that implements `Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider`.

But when I try to add the Class as a provider in the `AuthServiceProvider` it says `Class 'App\Extensions\CustomProvider' not found`. But when I remove `implements UserProvider` in my Class it returns `...must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider`.

My Code to create the provider:

```
Auth::provider('customProvider', function($app, array $config) {
  return new CustomProvider($app->make('request'));
});
```

The [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/authentication#adding-custom-user-providers) doesn't show the class itself.

**Edit:**
Here my custom provider:

```
namespace App\Extensions;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;

class CustomProvider implements UserProvider
{
    protected $request;

    public function __construct(Request $request) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    // Here the functions from the interface
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot a `use` statement, so it thinks the interface is in your own namespace.

Easily fixed.

`use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\UserProvider;`

Then implement it again and it will work!

Comment: my IDE already adds it automatically, without it the error is `Interface 'App\Extensions\UserProvider' not found`.

Comment: Without it, it thinks `UserProvider` is in your current namespace, `App\Extensions`. Hence it doesnt find `App\Extensions\UserProvider`